# Joining Zentyal Server Domain (3.4) 32 bit ver with a Windows 7 (Ultimate 64bit) or XP Pro

Tags: dns, zentyal

I want come direct to the point. I have installed Zentyal Server 3.4 ver as a Stand Alone Domain Controller and I have everything normally configured all Modules are up and I am trying to connect to my zentyal domain with a windows Xp or Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit pc or laptop , I see normally the POP up Window with the Username and the Password , I give normally my account and password (The account belong in Domain Admins Groups) but I become the error message:

> change computer name

at the join the domain 'ZENTYAL' attempt, the following error occurred:

> The specified domain does not exist or no connection could be made.

I have some Solutions tried :

1. Register Editor the following Keys changed or installed :

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
>   DWORD DomainCompatibilityMode = 1 DWORD DNSNameResolutionRequired = 0

2. The Key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Netlogon\Parameters RequireStrongKey = 0 changing.
3. Internet Time with the Zentyal server sychronising.
4. Internet Protokoll (TCP/IPv4) IP Address and DNS-Server Adress manually enter

Answer (score 1):

Try using only one NTP server (`time.windows.com`) for Zentyal Server Controller and Windows client.

Also try to avoid installing any other package at the beginning, it can destroy your configuration for some way.

Finally, remember to restart the PC after setting NTP on Windows to refresh the time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the Zentyal server as the primary DNS Server, with another (Google DNS at 8.8.8.8) below it to catch all the requests Zentyal can't handle.

This way, when the client looks for 'ZENTYAL', the Zentyal server 'hears' the request and provides its IP, while other requests that aren't for the Zentyal server (ex. www.google.com) will 'fall through' the Zentyal server and will be answered by the secondary DNS Server you specify.

To change the DNS Servers the client (on Windows 8, presumably down through Vista) contacts, open the Network and Sharing Center by right-clicking on either the Ethernet or Wireless icon in the tray or by going through the Control Panel. Then, click on the connection (eg. "WiFi (wifiname)") and select Properties. Select "Internet Protocol Version 4" in the list, then click 'Properties'. In the bottom panel, specify the Zentyal server's IP for the preferred server, and some other DNS server in the secondary server box.

To verify that you have the DNS set up right, open a command prompt and type `nslookup <domain>`. If you get a response that is a local IP (starts with `192.168`), and you can still browse the internet, then the DNS should be setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me!

[YOUTUBE TUTORIAl LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLoADYIk-tQ)

What this guy does is to sync USER-ZENTYAL.DOMAIN.LAN in ntp

> (Change time and zone -> Internet time [tab] -> change configuration -> Server: USER-ZENTYAL.domain.LAN -> Refresh now)